# Странный str_replace

Tags: php

```
$array = array();
$naw_arr = array(
 0 => "Керчь:в Керчи",
 1 => "Киев:в Киеве",
);
$cat['titleh1'] = "Аренда недвижимости Керчь";    
foreach ($naw_arr as $line) {    
    $array = explode(":", $line);
    $array[0] = trim($array[0]);
    $array[1] = trim($array[1]);
    $str = str_replace($array[0], $array[1], $cat['titleh1'], $count);
    if ($count > 0) {
        $cat['titleh1'] = $str;
        break;      
    }
}
```

Должно заменять "Аренда недвижимости Керчь" на "Аренда недвижимости в Керчи".
Но не заменяет, хотя на всякий случай добавил `trim();`
А если меняю местами строки в `$naw_arr` - то работает.
Что не так то?

Comment: а причем здесь в коде `$naw_arr` ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Без не нужных нагромождений, работает:

```
<?php
$naw_arr = array(
 0 => "Керчь:в Керчи",
 1 => "Киев:в Киеве",
);
$cat['titleh1'] = "Аренда недвижимости Керчь";
foreach ($naw_arr as $line) {
    $array = explode(":", $line);
    $str = str_replace($array[0], $array[1], $cat['titleh1'], $count);
    if ($count > 0) {
        $cat['titleh1'] = $str;
        break;
    }
}
echo var_dump($cat);
```

Результат:

```
array(1) {
  ["titleh1"]=>
  string(51) "Аренда недвижимости в Керчи"
}
```

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо.